# Repeat DataFrame rows against the child DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The source is a JSON file with Nested dictionaries.

I created a top-level defaultdict(dict) and a for loop to obtain the data frame for row 1 to 7, column State, Size, Pop.

Inside the above for loop, I again created another (child) defaultdict(dict) and for loop to obtain the data frame for row 1 to 2, column City, Size, Pop

I appended the child, defaultdict(dict)to the top defaultdict(dict)

Rows from parent data frame should be repeated against the child DataFrame

desired output

```
    State   Size    Pop   City      Size    Pop
1    MH     120     300    MU        100    150
2    MH     120     300    PU        80     110
3    MH     120     300    NG        75     120
4    MH     120     300    PC        85     110
5    GJ     110     250    SU        70     100
6    GJ     110     250    VA        75     80
7    GJ     110     250    AH        85     120
```

---

another example with input JSON

Input JSON :

```
{
    "datatop": [
        {
            "datastate": {
                "attributes": {
                    "Name": "ABC",
                    "Place": "123"
                },
                "children": [
                    {
                        "datacity": {
                            "attributes": {
                                "CName": "EFG",
                                "CPlace": "12345"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "datacity": {
                            "attributes": {
                                "CNAME": "HIJ",
                                "CPlace": "6789"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "datastate": {
                "attributes": {
                    "Name": "XYZ",
                    "Place": "456"
                },
                "children": [
                    {
                        "datacity": {
                            "attributes": {
                                "CName": "LMN",
                                "CPlace": "1123"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "datacity": {
                            "attributes": {
                                "CName": "OPQ",
                                "CPlace": "22345"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalCount": "2"
}
```

Expected output:

```
Name    Place   CName   CPlace
ABC     123     EFG     12345
ABC     123     HIJ     6798
XYZ     456     LMN     1123
XYZ     456     OPQ     22345
```

Comment: Please include example inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the expected output by changing my approach.

Earlier I was trying to repeat the rows in parent data frame (those I get from the parent for loop) against the rows of the Data frame from the child for loop.

New approach:
created an empty list before the parent for loop.
garbed the key value pairs from parent for loop to child for loop and created one big dictionary comprising of the key value pairs from parent as well as from child (nested) for loop. To make unique keys I used string concatenation of index of parent and child for loop.
Once the child for loop ends, outside of it (at the end of the parent for loop), I converted the dictionary to data frame and appended it to the list.
once the parent for loop completes, the list is complete the with data frames.
Lastly I did concatenation of the Data frames in the list.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

with open("./input.json") as file:
    filedata = json.load(file)

data = filedata['datatop']

dflist = []

for i in range (len(data)):

    attribute = (data[i])['datastate']['attributes']
    child = (((data[i]['datastate'])['children']))

    def_dct_chd = defaultdict(dict)

    # For Loop to Iterate over all the subnets of the L3OUT EPG
    for j in range (len(child)):
        def_dct_chd[str(i)+str(j)]['Name'] = attribute['Name']
        def_dct_chd[str(i)+str(j)]['Place'] = attribute['Place']
        def_dct_chd[str(i)+str(j)]['CName'] = child[j]['datacity']['attributes']['CName']
        def_dct_chd[str(i)+str(j)]['CPlace'] = child[j]['datacity']['attributes']['CPlace']

    # Create the Data Frames out of the dictionary and append it to the list
    dflist.append(pd.DataFrame(def_dct_chd).T)

# concatenate all the dictionaries inside the list
finaldf = pd.concat(dflist)

finaldf = finaldf.reset_index(drop=True)
print(finaldf)
```